# Gnuplot: fitting different curves

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, gnuplot, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am trying to fit some data in gnuplot. The data are different curves. I have three `.gnp` files: one for the mathematical procedure, one for calling the file to analyze and one that has to be launched in gnuplot.

What I get is this error, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
gnuplot> load '0-one_fit.gnp'

gnuplot> id = $0
           ^
```

> "0-one_fit.gnp" line 5: column() called from invalid context

This file should store sequence number from 0 to variable id. The sequence number is passed to this script from outside loop.gnp by command call.

The file says:

```
    id = $0
    filename = sprintf("FeCoBSiNbCu%04d.chi",id)
    fit [26:35.6] f110(x) filename u 1:2 via x110,A110,w110,a0,a1
    fit [42.3:45.1] f200(x) filename u 1:2 via x200,A200,w200,b0,b1
    fit [48:56.1] f23(x) filename u 1:2 via x2,A2,w2,x211,A211,w211,c0,c1


    entry1 = sprintf("%d\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%.1f\t%.1f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t",id,x110,x110_err,A110,A110_err,w110,w110_err)
    entry2 = sprintf("%.3f\t%.3f\t%.1f\t%.1f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t",x200,x200_err,A200,A200_err,w200,w200_err)
    entry3 = sprintf("%.3f\t%.3f\t%.1f\t%.1f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t",x2,x2_err,A2,A2_err,w2,w2_err)
    entry4 = sprintf("%.3f\t%.3f\t%.1f\t%.1f\t%.3f\t%.3f",x211,x211_err,A211,A211_err,w211,w211_err)
print entry1, entry2, entry3, entry4
```

Update:
I changed in the file with `id=ARG1` but now it gives me another error

```
gnuplot> call '0-one_fit.gnp' 0
     "0-one_fit.gnp" line 8: f_sprintf: attempt to print string value with numeric format
```

If I change now with `int(id)` it says:

```
load '0-one_fit.gnp'
     "0-one_fit.gnp" line 8: Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected
```

**UPDATE** 
I tried to run first the file called `0-in-situ.gnp` which contains the functions for peak fitting:

```
#### First peak: (110)

bg110(x) = a0 + a1*x

k110(x) = (x-x110)/w110

Gauss110(x) = A110*exp(-log(2)*k110(x)**2)
Cauchy110(x) = A110/(1 + k110(x)**2)

pV110(x) = alpha*Gauss110(x) + (1-alpha)*Cauchy110(x)

f110(x) = pV110(x) + bg110(x)


#### Second peak: (200)

bg200(x) = b0 + b1*x

k200(x) = (x-x200)/w200

Gauss200(x) = A200*exp(-log(2)*k200(x)**2)
Cauchy200(x) = A200/(1 + k200(x)**2)

pV200(x) = beta*Gauss200(x) + (1-beta)*Cauchy200(x)

f200(x) = pV200(x) + bg200(x)


#### Third peak & deconvolution (Q2 & 211):

bg(x) = c0 + c1*x

k2(x) = (x-x2)/w2
k211(x) = (x-x211)/w211

Gauss2(x) = A2*exp(-log(2)*k2(x)**2)
Cauchy2(x) = A2/(1 + k2(x)**2)
pV2(x) = gamma*Gauss2(x) + (1-gamma)*Cauchy2(x)

Gauss211(x) = A211*exp(-log(2)*k211(x)**2)
Cauchy211(x) = A211/(1 + k211(x)**2)
pV211(x) = delta*Gauss211(x) + (1-delta)*Cauchy211(x)

f23(x) = pV2(x) + pV211(x) + bg(x)

alpha = 0
beta = 0
gamma = 1
delta = 0

A110 = 15574
x110 = 31.1
w110 = 2.4 
a0 = 1760 
a1 = 6

A200 = 4153
x200 = 52.2
w200 = 3
b0 = 1500
b1 = 15

A2 = 1800
x2 = 51.6
w2 = 3
A211 = 1897
x211 = 76.6
w211 = 0.3
c0 = 1830
c1 = -2

#### Loop through all XRD patterns: 
load "0-loop.gnp"
```

The program goes, but when I open the file .dat which should contain the data, apparently it does not analyze all the curves but only the first. Is this a problem of the loop below?

```
call "0-one_fit.gnp" 447
call "0-one_fit.gnp" 448
call "0-one_fit.gnp" 449
call "0-one_fit.gnp" 450
call "0-one_fit.gnp" 451
call "0-one_fit.gnp" 452
```

Comment: Welcome! Please add more details to the question, such as what the other 3 gnp files are.

Comment: I have 3 gnp files: "0-in-situ.gnp" which contains the mathematical procedure to fit the data ( so the functions used and the initial values), "0-loop.gnp" which creates a loop to call all the files to analyze and then i have "0-one_fit.gnp" which has to be launched in gnuplot and plot the curves as .gif animations and .dat files.

Comment: which version of gnuplot are you running?

Comment: gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 7

Comment: I guess the problem is how and from where do you set this parameter `id`. Could you please show the code where your loop is? Is it within gnuplot or outside?

Comment: The loop is in the .gnp file 0-loop. The code is just `call 0-one_fit.gnp 1`, `call 0-one_fit.gnp 2`...and so on with all the data to fit

Comment: apparently, `id` is now considered as string. 
Convert it to integer via `int(id)`. Change the lines to 
`filename = sprintf("FeCoBSiNbCu%04d.chi",int(id))`
and `entry1 = sprintf("%d\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%.1f\t%.1f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t",int(id),x110,x110_err,A110,A110_err,w110,w110_err)`

Comment: `int(d)`, `x110`, `A110`, `w110` should be numbers since they come from the fitting,
what about `x110_err`, `A110_err`, `w110_err`? Where are they defined? 
As @John said, it's a bit difficult and too much guessing 
if we don't see a minimal rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$0` or `column(0)` within a plot command or a function which is used in a plot command. Elsewhere, I guess it's "invalid context".
Check the following example:

Also check `help using`, `help column`, `help pseudocolumns`.

```
reset session

$Data <<EOD
11 12 13 14 15
21 22 23 24 25
31 32 33 34 35
41 42 43 44 45
EOD

# id = $0            # does not work, invalid context
# id = column(0)     # does not work, invalid context
id(n) = column(n)    # within a function, works

plot $Data u           0:1 w lp    # works
plot $Data u        ($0):1 w lp    # works
plot $Data u (column(0)):1 w lp    # works
plot $Data u     (id(0)):1 w lp    # works
```

**Edit:**

I guess, I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to assign column values to a variable.

If you want to pass a parameter to a gnuplot routine, you could `call` a gnuplot file with parameters (instead of `load`).

`call '0-one_fit.gnp' 123`

Within `0-one_fit.gnp` you can access this value via `id = ARG1`. 
In earlier gnuplot versions ("old-style") this was `id=$0`.

Check `help call` and `help call old-style` (gnuplot 5.2)

Comment: I tried (see above) but it continues to give me error. Is it correct what I write?

Comment: it should be `call '0-one_fit.gnp' 0` and in the file `id=ARG1`.